# Show that the locus of midpoints of a family of parallel chords of a circle is a diameter perpendicular those chords.

Tags: euclidean-geometry

> Show that the locus of the midpoint of a family of parallel chords of a circle is a diameter which is perpendicular to the given family of chords.

Please help me understand the question with a figure .

Comment: Please, don't change the question. That trivializes my answer. If you want a new question then ask it again in a new thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the picture. All those chords are paralell and the midpoints are on a common perpendicular bisector. [image]

Comment: @ Maria Mazur how can we prove that the above statement is true

Comment: So you now understand the statement?

Comment: yes but I have to pen it on a paper

Comment: What does that mean?

Comment: I have to write a  proof for the above statement

Comment: You didn't ask that, you ask to help you understand the question, not to prove it for you. That is another question.

Comment: Please help me answer the question

Answer (score 0):

Let one parallel chord be $AB$ with midpoint $M$ and another one be $CD$ with midpoint $N$.  Draw the perpendicular bisector of $AB$, then also draw the transversal $BC$ and its perpendicular bisector.

These two perpendicular bisectors intersect at the center $O$ of the circle, so $OC$ is congruent with $OD$ meaning the perpendicular bisector of $AB$ (which passes through $M$) is also the perpendicular director of $CD$ (which passes through $N$).  Thereby the midpoints of both parallel chords must lie on the same line passing through the center $O$, QED.